# cakephp authenticate basic only valid users

Tags: http, cakephp, authentication

I am using the Auth with authenticate Basic.
Is there a way to check if the user is active = 1?
I would like to check that for the Form and the Basic method.
The Basic method is used, when a user log in from an iphone app sending username and password via http header.

```
public $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'api',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Basic' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Appuser',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'name'
                )
            ),
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Appuser',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'name'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `scope` setting of the AuthComponent and set it using the `ALL` constant:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'api',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            AuthComponent::ALL => array(      // Use this to apply common settings
                'userModel' => 'Appuser',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'name'
                ),
                'scope' => array(
                    'Appuser.active' => 1       // This is the check you need
                )
            ),
            'Basic',
            'Form'
        )
    )
);
```

For more info, refer to [this section in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers).