# Check a field before login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I done a user system on a website.
In my UsersController.php I have this method:

```
    public function login()
{
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Connexion établie', 'flash_success');
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Nom d'user ou mot de passe invalide, réessayer", 'flash_error');
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'indexes', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

It works very well, but I need to change it. In my database I have a field "validate" which is a boolean.
On login I want to log user if the field is true but I don't want to log him if the field is on false.

Thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp authenticate basic only valid users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932483/cakephp-authenticate-basic-only-valid-users)

Answer (score 0):

You need the scope field. You can either add it on the beforeFilter method For example:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'YourAuthComponent' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password'
            ),
            'userModel' => 'Users.User',

            //This is what you need
            'scope' => array(
                'User.active' => 1,
                'User.verified' => 1)
        )
    );
}
```

Or you can add the option to your components array at your AppController or UsersController.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

/**
* Components used from the application
*
* @var array
*/
public $components = array(

    'Auth'=> array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.active' => 1,
                    'User.verified' => 1)
                    )
                 )
             )
         ),
    );
}
```